# Custom Navigation Bar Image applied in each View Controller, not conforming to NSUserDefaults Synchronisation

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationbar, nsuserdefaults

I have a tab bar controller, consisting of 3 tabbed Table View Controllers (Timeline, Events and Settings) and I am working with themes.

If the user clicks on Settings, they can click on the "Themes" cell and select from a variety of themes.

Through the use of NSUserDefaults, I'm saving the theme in the didSelectCell of the SelectThemesTableViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.selectedTheme = selectedCell.textLabel.text;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:self.selectedTheme forKey:@"Theme"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

In the Timeline and Event view controller, I'm setting the background, the navigation bar image and the tab bar images in the viewWillAppear, depending on which cell the user selected like this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.selectedTheme = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"Theme"];

    if ([self.selectedTheme isEqualToString:@"Blur"])
    {
        // View Background
        UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Purplepink.png"]];
        self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundImageView;

        // Navigation Bar
        UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Purplepinknav.png"];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        // Tab Bar
        UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"SolidPurple.png"]
                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];

    }
    else if ([self.selectedTheme isEqualToString:@"Red Slanted"])
    {
        // View Background
        UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"RedSlanted.png"]];
        self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundImageView;

        // Navigation Bar
        UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"RedSlantedNav.png"];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        // Tab Bar
        UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"RedSlantedTab.png"]
                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];

    }

    else if ([self.selectedTheme isEqualToString:@"Twirl"])
    {
        // View Background
        UIImageView *backgroundImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Twirl.png"]];
        self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundImageView;

        // Navigation Bar
        UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ReddishBlackNav.png"];
        [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

        // Tab Bar
        UIImage *tabBackground = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"ReddishBlackTab.png"]
                                  resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)];
        [self.tabBarController.tabBar setBackgroundImage:tabBackground];
    }
```

When I set the theme in the SelectTheme, it works and when I go to Timeline Table View, the theme is fully applied with the background, navigation bar and with the tab bar image. If I exit the app and go back in, everything is still there.

However, the problem is: if I kill off the app from the multi-tasking on the simulator or my device and reopen my app, the background and tab bar is what I last set it as, but the Navigation Bar goes back to the default applied in the App Delegate. If I change to another tab and back to the Timeline, the navigation bar changes to the selected navigation before, but the problem is that initial view which loads up the default Nav Bar rather than the selected and if I change the tab and go back to the Timeline tab, it then shows again.

I have in the viewDidDisappear:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purplynav.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    UIImage *tabBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purplytab.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackgroundImage];

}
```

If I remove this viewDidAppear code, the same thing happens. 
Am I missing something? Why is the navigation bar not conforming to the NSUserDefaults?

The AppDelegate is below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NSLog(@"Is this getting called?");
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
    UIImage *navBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purplynav.png"];
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImage forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
    UIImage *tabBackgroundImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"purplytab.png"];
    [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackgroundImage];
    ...
}
```

EDIT: I have added some logging as per the comment. The NSLog in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions in the AppDelegate always gets run first. Right after this, the viewWillAppear of the Timeline Table View (the initial view controller) gets called with the NSLog in there.

This explains why the navigation bar goes back to the default the very first time the application is launched after it was killed from the multitasking (or not opened for hours). However, I do not necessarily need to set the code in the AppDelegate. At first, the App had no themes and so setting the AppDelegate's Nav bar was important. However now, I want to start the app off with a theme, but when a new theme is selected, to NOT push forward the App Delegate's Nav Bar the very first time the app is run after being killed.

Any assistance on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the default settings called in the app delegate? Are you using storyboard? Add logs and check which order your code runs in...

Comment: Thanks @Wain - the default settings are being called in the App Delegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. I also have the default tab bar image in that didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method which doesn't get called when killing off the app from the multitasking. I'm using all storyboards here for the entire app. Logging in the AppDelegate - that gets called when I launch the app, but doesn't get hit when I close the app, but would get called when I kill the app from the multitasking. Thanks Wain

Comment: Sorry @Wain, do you have any further thoughts with this issue?

Comment: Did you add logging and check which code is called and when?

Comment: I have added the comments from the Logging to the question at the end. The AppDelegate gets called right before the viewWillAppear every time.. which sort of explains why this is working the way it is, but I don't get how to fix this..

Comment: The app delegate doesn't have a nav bar. Why don't you use the `UIAppearance` proxy directly when the theme is changed and in the app delegate (using the saved value)?

Comment: @Wain that was absolutely brilliant. I'm not sure why I thought I couldn't use the UIAppearance proxy in the AppDelegate itself; I think I just didn't think it through properly. That worked like an absolute charm. Thanks so much. Could I ask you to "answer" this so I can accept it please? Thanks so much again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim down and simplify your solution so that you configure all of the theme based UI using `UIAppearance` proxy in 2 places:

1. The app delegate - using the stored settings (best if this is a call to your theme manager)
2. The theme manager - using the newly stored settings

In this way your theme code is contained and organised and you always have the appropriate theme applied (instead of some default).

Comment: Thanks so much @Wain - the option 1 worked like an absolutely treat here.